# Using subversion (svn) with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, subversion

I'd like to do subversion (svn) activities directly from Eclipse 2019-06.  I'm aware of a [2010 StackOverflow recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665759/what-is-a-good-svn-plugin-for-eclipse) for an Eclipse plugin, but software can change over the course of 9 years.  What plugin do you recommend for svn activity in Eclipse?

My main criteria are ease of installation, configuration, and usage.  I'm less interested in completeness of functionality, since I plan to do mostly basic svn operations.